# Metamask Wallet Change in Dapp

Tags: metamask, dapps, dapp-development, authentication

I wonder something about the usage of the metamask wallet for Dapp. I have implemented an Authentication mechanism to my Dapp with Keycloak, and I ask for blockchain wallet addresses of the users in the registration.

However, I need to be sure that when the user uses my Dapp, he/she uses the address they provided in the registration; otherwise, I need to revoke their request.

I use metamask as a wallet provider; thank you.

Comment: Just ignore the requests that come from the account that is not in your database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eth_accounts` JSON-RPC call which returns the list of accounts owned by the client. Metamask API implements it with :

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
const currentAccount = accounts[0];
```

The first item of the list should return the current used account.

Then just compare the returned value with the registered account.